# Convert Dropdown Menu Script to be Android-friendly?

Tags: javascript, android, drop-down-menu

I have the following simple script which works fine on all browsers and the iPhone/iPad, but not Android devices. I was wondering how to make it work with Android?

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

// Copyright 2006-2007 javascript-array.com

var timeout = 500;
var closetimer  = 0;
var ddmenuitem  = 0;

// open hidden layer
function mopen(id)
{   
    // cancel close timer
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // get new layer and show it
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
// close showed layer
function mclose()
{
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

// go close timer
function mclosetime()
{
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

// cancel close timer
function mcancelclosetime()
{
    if(closetimer)
    {
        window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
        closetimer = null;
    }
}

// close layer when click-out
document.onclick = mclose; 

// -->
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="test"><a href="#" 
        onmouseover="mopen('m4')" onmouseout="mclosetime()" class="test2">CLASSES</a>
        <div id="m4" 
           onmouseover="mcancelclosetime()" onmouseout="mclosetime()">
        <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/category/2013-gall">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/olderclasses/">Older Classes</a>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Live: http://www.anthonyteacher.com

I tried adding onClick="mopen('m4')", but that didn't seem to work. I think I need to use an eventhandler with touchstart, but not sure how to implement it.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You may find my Houdini script useful: http://cferdinandi.github.io/houdini/

**Update**

To make this work on click AND on hover, grab the jQuery version. On line 14, update this:

```
$('.collapse-toggle').click(function(e) {
```

To instead say this:

```
$('.collapse-toggle').on('click hover', function(e) {
```

Comment: That's useful only for Android. The menu needs to retain onhover capabilities for regular PCs.

Comment: Huh? It works on ANY device that supports JavaScript. Hover drop downs suck. They trigger falsely all the time. That said, you can easily modify the jQuery version of Houdini to work on click OR hover. Updated comment above to reflect this.

Comment: I made the modificaiton you mentioned and set up the jQuery version. The hover doesn't work. And I also tried incorporating it into my already existing menu, with no luck. I did: `<li class="test">
        <a class="collapse active" data-target="#hide-me">
    <span class="collapse-text-show">CLASSES</span>
    <span class="collapse-text-hide">CLASSES</span>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse-toggle" id="hide-me">
<a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/category/2013-gall">Google</a>
 <a href="http://www.anthonyteacher.com/olderclasses/">Older Classes</a>
    </div>
    </li>`